# PHP udp server: unable to connect to remote host

Tags: php

I get this error message, when try connect to tiny UDP server. The source code is minimized and looks like so:

```
//server.php

$server_host = '127.0.0.1';
$server_port = 21665;
$poll_interval = 0.5;
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
socket_bind($socket, $server_host, $server_port);

$clients = [$socket];
while(true) {
    $read = $clients;
    $write = [];
    $except = [];

    if (socket_select($read, $write, $except, $poll_interval) < 1){
        continue;
    }

    if (in_array($socket, $read)) {
        echo "Client submitted request!\n";
        //request parsing                   
    }                
}
```

So, when I run the server with `$ php server.php` it hangs for ever, as it should. When however I try to connect to it through telnet to post a request I get an error message:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 21665
Trying 127.0.0.1 ...
Telnet: unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

What I'm doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I'm doing wrong

You are using telnet (a TCP client) to try to connect to a UDP port.

> how can I fix it

Use a client that supports UDP, for example netcat as explained in this answer: [telnet counterpart for udp](https://serverfault.com/questions/395342/telnet-counterpart-for-udp)

```
nc -u <host> <port>
```

Start typing and press enter.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I will check it in a minute.